# Drupal text fields CSS change

Tags: php, drupal

I am using the web form module to create a web form. Now I want to customize each field's style differently.

I have changed the CSS in the web form but it makes changes on each field. I want a different style on each field.

Please tell me how can make these changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a link regarding theming Drupal Webforms.

There's lots of info on Google if you do a search as well.

[Theming drupal webforms](http://drupal.org/node/79086)

Comment: I have tried these function but it gave no sufficient result.
As these gave me no change in any fields.
Please give any other solution.

Comment: Google is your friend :) 

You should maybe post some of your code so that people on here can see what your doing and help you more easily.